# Ionic 3 Angular 5 get request from webService

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, get, request, ionic3

I'm trying to get data from a local web service but I cannot print the values ​​in the app.

This is my code:

*team-data.ts*:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TeamDataProvider {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello TeamDataProvider Provider');
  }

 apiUrl="http://localhost/MyWebService/api/getteams.php";

 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const err = error || '';
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

  getTeams(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  getRemoteData(){
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map(res => res).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

*app.module.ts*:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TeamDataProvider } from '../providers/team-data/team-data';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    TeamDataProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*home.ts*:

```
import { TeamDataProvider } from '../../providers/team-data/team-data';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public teamDataProvider: TeamDataProvider) {

   this.getTeam();

  }

  teams: string[];
  errorMessage: string;

  getTeam() {
    this.teamDataProvider.getTeams()
       .subscribe(
        teams => this.teams = teams,
         error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.teamDataProvider.getRemoteData();
  } 
}
```

*home.html:*

```
   <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>
        Team List
      </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <h2>Team List</h2>
      <ion-list inset>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let team of teams">
          <p>{{team.id}}</p>
          <p>{{team.name}}</p>
          <p>{{team.number}}</p>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

When I run `ionic serve -l`:

> Runtime Error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

What did I wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `this.teams` inside `getTeam() ` of home.ts? you are missing an `aync` pipe. in html

Comment: did you get the data from web service?

Comment: can you share the data in this.teams which you receive from the service.

Comment: team-data.ts:49 
{teams: Array(4)}
teams
:
Array(4)
0
:
{id: 2, name: "updated", member: 4}
1
:
{id: 3, name: "cambiato", member: 8}
2
:
{id: 4, name: "test", member: 3}
3
:
{id: 5, name: "sadasd", member: 2}
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues visible at glance:

- In your home.ts AND your provider you declare variables after
  constructor function. You should do it BEFORE.
- Also noted your "teams" var is expected to be Array of objects type and it was
  string[]. Make sure it is not only typed but also has initial value
  (like empty array) etc
- Also it is best to use IonViewDidLoad lifecycle hook for getTeams.
  Use constructor mostly to assign default/initial values to declared
  vars

```js
import { TeamDataProvider } from '../../providers/team-data/team-data';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  teams: Array<any> = [];
  errorMessage: string; 
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public teamDataProvider: TeamDataProvider) {
  }

  getTeam() {
    this.teamDataProvider.getTeams()
       .subscribe(
        teams => this.teams = teams,
         error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.teamDataProvider.getRemoteData();
   this.getTeam();
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, I changed the type of the array and placed the variables before the constructor, but unfortunately the problem persists:
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. HomePage.html:12

Comment: Can you try removing this : .map(this.extractData) from your getTeams and see what happens?

Comment: Most likely before your this.teams gets any data it gets assigned the obj {} and template fails.

Comment: i change the func like this:
 getTeams(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }


but unfortunately it returns the same error :

Runtime Error
Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed